# I want my aws lamda to not return anything until the mysql query has been executed completely on node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, aws-lambda

I will provide the code first which is an AWS node.js Lambda function

```
    const mysql = require('mysql');
       const con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'testtest.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        user: 'test',
        password: 'test',
        database: 'test',
    });      
    exports.handler = function(event,context,callback){
        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
        var queryResult=[];
        var searchbyArray = (event.searchby);
        var len = searchbyArray.length;
        getResult(len,searchbyArray,function(err,data){
            if(err){console.log("the error is "+err);}
            else{
                callback(null,data);
            }
        });
};

function getResult(len,searchbyArray,cb){
    var results=[];
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        console.log("before loop"+i);
        var sql ="SELECT * FROM aa_customer_device WHERE id LIKE '%"+searchbyArray[i]+"%'";
        con.query(sql,function(err,result){
        if (err){cb(err,null);}
        else{
            results.push(result);
        }
      });
    }
   cb(null,results);
}
```

Here, the cb(null, results) gets executed before the for loops gets completed since the con.query(...) is an async function(guess that's what its called) and always returns an empty array in 'results' which is then returned by the handler in its callback function.

Is there any way I can write the code in node.js so that it follows the sequence like

- finish executing all the con.query(...) inside the for loop
- push the resulting array from each loop iteration to the 'results' array
- only after the above two steps has been completed call the cb(null,results)

what's happening here is the cb(null, results) is being executed way before the for loop gets a chance to store the desired information in the results array.

is there any way to accomplish what I want using node.js. I was suggested to use promises, async,await but form what I read all of those solutions won't exactly solve my problem.

Comment: for(var i=0; i<len; i++){} here what is len?  should it be searchbyArray.length?

Comment: its searchbyArray.length... I have passed len as an argument while calling the getResult()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually detect when the last request have completed:

```
function getResult(len,searchbyArray,cb){
    var results=[];
    var requestCount = 0;
    var error = null;

    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){

        requestCount++; // count the requests made

        var sql ="SELECT * FROM aa_customer_device WHERE id LIKE '%"+searchbyArray[i]+"%'";
        con.query(sql,function(err,result){
            // Note: All logic needs to happen here since
            //       this is the ONLY place where code gets
            //       executed in the FUTURE instead of now.

            requestCount --; // count completed requests

            if (err){error = err}
            else{
                results.push(result);

                if (requestCount === 0) {
                    if (error) cb(error,null);   // "return" error
                    else       cb(results);      // "return" results
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

#### With async/await

If you have access to an ES6 environment you can use async/await to make this much easier to read. First you need to promisify the query:

```
// Promisify con.query:
function query (con, sql) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else     resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

async function getResult(len,searchbyArray,cb){
    var results=[];

    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        var sql ="SELECT * FROM aa_customer_device WHERE id LIKE '%"+searchbyArray[i]+"%'";

        try {
            var result = await query(con, sql);
            results.push(result);
        }
        catch (err) {
            cb(err,null);
            return; // stop processing
        }
    }
    cb(results);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already got the problem. `cb(null , results)` is not waiting for the query to complete.  In order to make it wait, as you already mentioned, you can use promise/async-await.

here is how you can write an `async/await` code to achieve what you are trying to do.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const promisify = require('util').promisify;

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'testtest.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
  user: 'test',
  password: 'test',
  database: 'test',
});

// con.connect uses a callback, we can use util.promify to convert it to promise driven
const connect = promisify(con.connect);

// con.query uses a callback, we can use util.promify to convert it to promise driven
const query = promisify(con.query);

exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  const queryResult = [];
  const searchbyArray = (event.searchby);
  const len = searchbyArray.length;

  try {

    // wait for the connection to be established.
    await connect();

    const data = getResult(len, searchbyArray);

    // return the lambda success result
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      responseBody: JSON.stringify(data)
    }

  } catch(err) {
    console.log("the error is " + err)

    // return the lambda failure result
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      responseBody: err.message
    }
  }
};

async function getResult(len, searchbyArray, cb) {
  const results = [];
  for (const i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    console.log("before loop" + i);

    const sql = `SELECT * FROM aa_customer_device WHERE id LIKE '%${searchbyArray[i]}%'`;

    // wait for the query to complete
    const results = await query(sql);
    results.push(result);
  }
  return results;
}
```

hope this helps, feel free to ask me if you don't understand this code.

Comment: Is that what you were looking for

Comment: I did try to use your code, there seems to be some kind of error at the line 'const results = await query(sql);' can't exactly remember what the error was. @slebetman answer did the trick for me and i have accepted that as the approved answer for now.

Answer (score 1):

Reason is `con.query()` is a callback function. Callbacks are asynchronous, which means it will not execute in order. you have two options.

- Use await keyword (If possible)
- Wrap function by using Promise

I actually don't know AWS Lambda Mysql support async/await hence I will demonstrate the second option.These two options do the same thing but different patterns.

Situation in here is callbacks execute asynchronously. It will not "await" until result comes that's why you got an empty array.This is how async function behave.It is very important topic to understand, if you are going to develop even server less application in Node js or Java script.Please comment if you want more explanation.

Here you can wrap `con.query()` function by using Promise.

```
       const con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'testtest.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        user: 'test',
        password: 'test',
        database: 'test',
    });      
    exports.handler = async (event,context,callback)=>{
        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
        var queryResult=[];
        var searchbyArray = (event.searchby);
        var len = searchbyArray.length;
        try{
            const result = await Promise.all(getResult(searchbyArray));
        }catch (error){
            console.log("the error is "+err);
        }
};

const getResult = async (searchbyArray) =>{
    const result = searchbyArray.map(searchItem=>{
        var sql =`SELECT * FROM aa_customer_device WHERE id LIKE %${searchItem}%`;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
                if (err) 
                    reject(err);
                else     
                    resolve(result);
            });
        });
    })
    return result;
}
```

I have replace the for loop with map instead of push to array and used Promise.all this application will run more fast instead of await in each loop cycle.